What does "shot" mean?

On the other hand, popular culture continues to evolve as products and styles from different cultures mix and combine in new and interesting ways. For example, although superstars from the United States and the United Kingdom dominate the world music industry, a movement is taking place to include more diverse styles and performers. In Europe, local music acts are grabbing a larger share of the market and overtaking the popularity of international (that is, English-speaking) acts. Revenue from Spanish-language music has quadrupled in five years. In Asia, new songs are being written to accompany promotions for American movies. For example, in Hong Kong the movie Lethal Weapon 4 was promoted with a song by a local heavy metal band called “Beyond.” Shots from the movie were mixed with clips of band members, even though the band does not appear in the film and the song is not included on the soundtrack.

Which definition is better for "shot"? (Source: Focus on Vocabulary 2)

a photograph
a scene in a film that is filmed continuously by one camera
a single sequence of a motion picture or a television program shot by one camera without interruption
a short piece in a film in which there is a single action or a short series of actions


this feels like homework. While we can all tell you what we think, that may not be what the marker wants you to answer.

Glad that was edited because it made no sense

I am a teacher. I am trying to clarify the usage for my students.

I think they are all accurate just what the context it is when talking about it you can figure out the meaning.

I'm not clear on the distinction between definitions 2 and 3?

It seems very likely that they mean 'footage', since the film was already in production when the band was hired to produce a song for the film.

Yeah, clips, bits, chinks, anything could be appplied

I’m voting to close this question because it is about (understanding) the English language and has nothing to do with film appreciation.

TL;DR:
This really needs that video for context
Otherwise we are guessing as to how loosely the term shot has been applied. Otherwise:

*For example, in Hong Kong the movie Lethal Weapon 4 was promoted with a song by a local heavy metal band called “Beyond.”
Shots from the movie were mixed with clips of band members, even though the band does not appear in the film and the song is not included on the soundtrack.*

Your options seem limited (which is why it read like homework, and you just wanted an answer), so the context in which they are used would be important:

1. a photograph

Because we are talking in motion picture terms, if it was a photograph the term would a 'frame', from a series of frames that make up a sequence. If you were taking about a stills camera, then each frame would be a shot, loosely, but since we are not, that would be incorrect.

2. a scene in a film that is filmed continuously by one camera

Since a scene can also be composed of many different shots, by different cameras, this would be incorrect.

3. a single sequence of a motion picture or a television program shot by one camera without interruption

This is the closest to a shot, technically.

4. a short piece in a film in which there is a single action or a short series of actions

This can also be described as a scene, much like 2.
From this, context is important.
I have not seen the music video mentioned, so unable to determine how loosely the term 'shots' is being used here.
Sources:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/84110.Film_Directing_Shot_by_Shot
https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/what-is-a-shot-list-example/#:~:text=A%20shot%20list%20is%20a,preparedness%20for%20the%20film%20crew.
From the above, this is a scene, composed of different shots (and potentially filmed with different cameras with different lenses to achieve the.. shot):

